# NameError when checking 'if (gets = a)'

Tags: ruby, class, nameerror

Please help me how to fix my code... It keeps saying name error. How do I fix it. I tried adding $ sign to make it a global variable but it still says name error.

```
class Stack 
  def initialize
    @store = []
  end

  def push (a)
    @store.push (a)
  end

  def pop
    @store.pop
  end
end

puts "Press a or b to add or remove Pinball: " #make the user choose to press a or b to stack
press = gets.downcase 

press = a      # if user selected a, add pinball to array
if (press = a)
  l1 = stack.new
  l1.push(Pinball)
  puts L1
end

press = b    # if user selected b, remove pinball to array
if (press = b)
  r2 = stack.new
  r2.pop
  puts r2
  end
end
```

Comment: What line has the error?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete error message as it appears in the console.

Comment: What is the "Pinball"?

Comment: I flagged as off-topic, typo. Accoding to your question, you have an error because you do not understand Ruby fully. In that, you think `=` operates how it does in regular math. No, that is assignment. `==` is what you need. This can be seen as a small typo or a beginner's problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has several issues. I'll focus on reading / processing the user input.

First of all: don't try to fix error by blindly changing your code (*"I tried adding $ sign to make it a global variable"*). This just makes things worse. Instead, take a step back and try to understand the error message. It usually contains some useful information or at least a line number that points you in the right direction.

I often use [IRB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Ruby_Shell) to try out small pieces of code. For larger code, I prefer test driven development.

#### The `NameError`

Let's review your code. This line reads the user input, "downcases" it and assigns it to the variable `press`:

```
press = gets.downcase
```

The next line attempts to assign the variable or method `a` to `press` and results in an error:

```
press = a
#=> NameError: undefined local variable or method `a'
```

Ruby raises this error because you don't have such variable or method - `a` is undefined. And you probably don't want to assign to `press` either, because it would overwrite the user input. Just remove that line.

#### Fixing the user input

The next line contains the same code:

```
if (press = a)
```

According to the comment, you want to check *"if user selected a"*. Maybe it's just a typographical error, but since you are repeating this mistake, let's get this sorted out:

- `=` (one equals sign) is the *assignment operator* and it's used for [assignment](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html):

  ```
  v = 5
  v #=> 5
  ```
- `==` (two equals signs) is the *comparison operator* and it's used to compare two objects. It returns `true` if the objects are equal and `false` otherwise:

  ```
  1 == 1         #=> true
  1 == 2         #=> false

  "foo" == "foo" #=> true
  "foo" == "bar" #=> false

  v == 5         #=> true
  v == 3         #=> false
  ```

  `==` is often used in `if` statements.

Back to our code. To check if `press` equals `a`, we have to use the comparison operator `==`:

```
if (press == a)
```

But again, `a` is undefined. We have to replace the *variable* `a` with the *character* `"a"`, because the users enters characters:

```
if (press == "a")
```

A small detail is still missing. Did you notice that in order to enter an *a*, you actually have to press *two* keys <kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>return</kbd>? Both keys produce a character:

- <kbd>a</kbd> produces `"a"`
- <kbd>return</kbd> produces `"\n"` - called [newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) or end of line (EOL)

[`gets`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) returns the entire input, including the newline, so `press` actually contains two characters:

```
press #=> "a\n"
```

There are two options - either check for both characters:

```
if (press == "a\n")
```

Or get rid of the newline. Because this is such a common operation, Ruby provides a dedicated method [`String#chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-chomp):

> Returns a new `String` with the given record separator removed from the end of `str` (if present)

We can call this method right after reading the string:

```
press = gets.chomp.downcase
```

The whole code:

```
puts "Press a or b to add or remove Pinball: "
press = gets.chomp.downcase 

if press == 'a'
  # ...
end
```

Note that the parentheses can be omitted.

#### Other issues

Your program currently creates a new stack every time the user enters an *a* or a *b* but you probably want to add elements to and remove elements from a single stack. Therefore, you should create this stack in the beginning:

```
stack = Stack.new
```

The letter case is very important: `Stack` (uppercase `S`) is your class, whereas `stack` (lowercase) is a variable (I could have used `foo` or any other valid [variable name](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Local+Variable+Names)). `Stack.new` returns a new `Stack` instance that is assigned to `stack`.

To `push` / `pop` to that stack:

```
if press == 'a'
  stack.push('Pinball')
end

if press == 'b'
  stack.pop
end
```

You'll also need a loop in order to process more than a single input. Something like:

```
loop do
  puts "Press a or b to add or remove Pinball: "
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the problem is that your class is called `Stack` but you keep calling `stack.new`. Try `Stack.new` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
class Stack
  def initialize
      @store = []
  end

  def push(a)
      @store.push(a)
  end

  def pop
    @store.pop
  end
end

puts "Press a or b to add or remove Pinball: " #make the user choose to press a or b to stack
press = gets.downcase.strip
puts "press:#{press}"

l1 = Stack.new  # class names should begin with an uppercase letter 

# a or b should be a string
if press == "a" # check the value of two operands are equal or not, you should use `==` operator
  l1.push("Pinball")
  puts "l1: #{l1.inspect}"
elsif press == "b"
  l1.pop()
  puts "l1: #{l1.inspect}"
end
```

Output:

```
ress a or b to add or remove Pinball:
a
l1: #<Stack:0x007ff8d18f2a38 @store=["Pinball"]>

Press a or b to add or remove Pinball:
b
l1: #<Stack:0x007f9feb8e4aa8 @store=[]>
```